Is the jest testing library is worked in fuse theme
I want to run my test cases in fusetheme react.js project using jest library.In one file.js there i used fusecomponent below
import FusePageCarded from "@fuse/core/FusePageCarded";
But during npm run test of file.test.js i get below errors
● Test suite failed to run
Cannot find module '@fuse/core/FusePageCarded' from 'src/app/utils/utils.js' 

I expected to run file.test.js perfectly without fusetheme error
